# automatically zoom out the image after Zoom in the image

Tags: android, android-imageview, zooming

I am  developing the *RDP* application using *Android 3.0*. I am displaying the images through *InputStream* (from server socket) continuously. Where I customize [**TouchImageView.java**](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java) for Zoom in and zoom out the images and gesture events.

After Zoom in the image in *Android 3.0* (Acer Tablet device), For next image (*InputStream* from server) the image is automatically Zoom out and displayed in normal mode.
But in *Android 4.0* (Samsung Tablet device), For next image (*InputStream* from server socket) the image is displayed in Zoom mode.

Where I need unique behavior for the both devices i.e After the zoom in, the next image(input stream from server socket) is displayed in Zoom mode.

Comment: I got the solution, The werid behavior is due to onMeasure() is called before image is set to imageView at very first time in samsung where as in Acer the onMeasure() is called for every call of setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm).